# bindingSource.Filter - When to use AND vs OR

Tags: c#, datatable, bindingsource

I'm learning to use bindingSource.Filter and It's been driving me nuts for the past couple of days.

I have 7 columns and am trying to create a filter along the lines of "if the row has checked values from multiple ListCheckBoxes, then adjust the rows to display the rows that meet the criteria." Basically like excel.

Here is an example:
`First Name` | `Last Name` | `EmployeeID`| `Department` // <-- column headers

first row example = `John` | `Doe` | `001` | `IT`

second row example = `Jane` | `Doe` | `002` | `HR`

third row example = `Bob` | `Doe` | `003` | `Logistics`

fourth row example = `Sally` | `Doe` | `004` | `Logistics`

Of course, this is just an example, but how can I filter with more than 3 columns?
I've found that using OR between 2 of the SAME or 2 different columns works.

Filtering one column:

For example: `[First Name] = 'John' OR [First Name] = 'Jane'` <-- works. will show 2 rows with Jane and John

Filtering 2 columns:
`[First Name] = 'John' OR [First Name] = 'Jane' AND [Department] = 'IT'` <-- works. will show 1 row as expected with John.

Filtering with 3 columns:
`[First Name] = 'John' AND [FirstName] = 'Jane' OR [Last Name] = 'Doe' AND [Department] = 'HR'` <-- works but i dont see the rule of when to use AND / OR

The last filter works but it is not clear to me when to use AND and when to use OR.

I would think that using AND everywhere would solve the issue but it doesn't. My datatable just ends up showing 0 results.

I've searched around for an article or anything that would explain the filtering logic but the closest I've found is [this article for Row Filter](https://www.csharp-examples.net/dataview-rowfilter/) which might be the same thing more or less?

Any help or direction is appreciated.

Also if anyone knows a better way to multi-filter a datatable other than just using bindingsource.Filter. Dont be shy.

Comment: I think i figured it out. Turns out i wasnt reading the article close enough and wasnt using the parentheses to enclose the OR statements and it also looks like i had a trailing \r in my filter that needs to be escaped or trimmed.

Comment: `[First Name] = 'John' AND [FirstName] = 'Jane' OR [Last Name] = 'Doe' AND [Department] = 'HR'` is illogical however you cut it - [First Name] can only be John Or Jane, not John And Jane

Answer (score 0):

> it is not clear to me when to use AND and when to use OR

The problem probably stems from how you speak. I suspect you might say "I want all blue cars and all red trucks" - it's actually OR in computer terms. If you said "For every item in the list, I only want to see it if it's a blue car or if it's a red truck" it's more clear, it's just that humans tend not to speak that way - they say "and" when really they mean "or":

```
(type = 'car' AND color = 'blue) OR (type = 'truck' AND color = 'red')
```

- AND has to make sense *within a row*
- OR has to make sense *across different rows as well as within a row*

```
Name = 'John' AND Name = 'Mary'
```

That one doesn't make sense. No-one has a name that is simultaneously John and Mary. They have a name of John OR they have a name of Mary

Remember that AND works within a row

```
John Smith
Mary Jones

firstname = 'john' AND lastname = 'jones;'
```

No single row matches this - AND works within the row. No row has a first name of john and a last name of jones

```
firstname = 'john' OR lastname = 'jones'
```

Both rows come back - the first row because firstname is john. The second row because lastname is jones. OR works across rows as well as within a row. OR can cope with you repeating the same thing:

```
firstname = 'john' OR firstname = 'mary'
```

All these things become a truth statement, evaluated per row. For the john smith row:

```
firstname = 'john'    --> it's true
OR 
firstname = 'mary'    --> it's false
```

- `true or true` is `true`
- `true and true` is `true`
- `true or false` is `true`
- `true and false` is `false`
- `false or false` is `false`
- `false and false` is `false`

---

Use parentheses to group logical combinations

This is unclear:

```
firstname = 'john' and lastname = 'smith' OR firstname = 'mary' and lastname = 'jones'
```

It makes sense like this:

```
(firstname = 'john' and lastname = 'smith') OR (firstname = 'mary' and lastname = 'jones')
```

It doesn't make sense in any other way

```
firstname = 'john' and (lastname = 'smith' OR firstname = 'mary') and lastname = 'jones'
(firstname = 'john' and lastname = 'smith' OR firstname = 'mary') and lastname = 'jones'
firstname = 'john' and (lastname = 'smith' OR firstname = 'mary' and lastname = 'jones')
```